# React useReducer: Payload is received, state not updated

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks, use-reducer, leaflet-routing-machine

I am using this [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively/) to help with using the `useReducer` hook.

I have created this context component because I am using the **react-leaflet** routing machine to create markers for the route and I'd like to save the **latitude** and **longitude** in local storage; I am able to save them initially but I can't update them!

Essentially in my `UserContext` component, I have created this **reducer** function:

```
function userReducer(state, { type, payload }) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse': {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: payload.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo
        };
      }
      case 'updateMarkers': {
        console.log('type, payload ', type, payload);
        return {
          ...state,

          ...state.markers.map(element => {
            console.log('element.alt === payload.alt ', element.alt === payload.alt);
            return element.alt === payload.alt ? { ...element, ...payload } : element;
          })
        };
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${type}`);
      }
    }
  }
```

So you can see there is a `console.log` in the case clause,

```
  case 'updateMarkers': {
            console.log('type, payload ', type, payload);
            return {
              ...state,

type, payload  updateMarkers LatLng {lat: 40.74154270838886, lng: -73.76230053137989, alt: "current location"} alt: "current location"lat: 40.74154270838886lng: -73.76230053137989
```

So it actually **IS** getting passed in the reducer, but the state is not being updated!

```
This is the complete component :


import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import { getUserAvatar } from '../../utils/index';

import { parse, stringify } from 'flatted';

var initialState = {
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg',
  isRoutingVisible: false,
  removeRoutingMachine: false,
  isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: true,
  markers: [],
  currentMap: {}
};

var UserContext = React.createContext();

function setLocalStorage(key, value) {
  function isJson(item) {
    item = typeof item !== 'string' ? JSON.stringify(item) : item;

    try {
      item = JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }

    if (typeof item === 'object' && item !== null) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  try {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (errors) {
    // catch possible errors:
    console.log(errors);
  }
}

function getLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  try {
    const value = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return value ? JSON.parse(value) : initialValue;
  } catch (e) {
    return initialValue;
  }
}

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getLocalStorage('user', initialState));
  const [isAvatarUploading, setIsAvatarUploading] = useState(true);

  function userReducer(state, { type, payload }) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse': {
        return {
          ...state,
          isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: payload.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo
        };
      }
      case 'updateMarkers': {
        console.log('type, payload ', type, payload);
        return {
          ...state,

          ...state.markers.map(element => {
            console.log('element.alt === payload.alt ', element.alt === payload.alt);
            return element.alt === payload.alt ? { ...element, ...payload } : element;
          })
        };
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${type}`);
      }
    }
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, initialState);

  // console.log('user ', user);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalStorage('user', user);
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('user.isRoutingVisibile ', user.isRoutingVisibile);
  }, [user.isRoutingVisibile]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('state', state);
    if (user.markers.length === 2) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwoFalse',
        payload: { isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo: false }
      });
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(user.markers)]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.id) {
      getUserAvatar()
        .then(userAvatar => {
          setIsAvatarUploading(false);
          setUser(user => ({ ...user, avatar: userAvatar }));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('error thrown from getUserAvatar', err));
    } else {
      console.log('No user yet!');
    }
  }, [user.id]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userId: user.id,

        setUserId: id => setUser({ ...user, id }),

        userAvatar: user.avatar,

        setUserAvatar: avatar => setUser({ ...user, avatar }),

        isAvatarUploading: isAvatarUploading,

        userImages: user.images,

        setUserImages: images => setUser({ ...user, images }),

        userMarkers: user.markers,

        setUserMarkers: marker => {
          state.isLengthOfMarkersLessThanTwo
            ? setUser(user => ({
                ...user,
                markers: [...user.markers, marker]
              }))
            : () => null;
        },

        setUpdateUserMarker: dispatch,

        deleteUserMarkers: () => {
          setUser({
            ...user,
            markers: [
              ...user.markers.filter(function(e, i, a) {
                return e !== a[a.length - 1];
              })
            ]
          });
        },

        setUserMarkersToNull: () =>
          setUser({
            ...user,
            markers: null
          }),

        userMap: user.currentMap,

        setUserCurrentMap: map =>
          setUser({ ...user, currentMap: { ...user.currentMap, map } }),

        removeRoutingMachine: user.removeRoutingMachine,

        resetUserMarkers: () => {
          console.log('fired setIsRoutingVisibileToTrue');
          setUser({
            ...user,
            removeRoutingMachine: true,
            isRoutingVisible: false,

            markers: []
          });
        },

        isRoutingVisibile: user.isRoutingVisible,

        setIsRoutingVisibileToTrue: () => {
          console.log('fired setIsRoutingVisibileToTrue');
          setUser({
            ...user,
            isRoutingVisible: true
          });
        },

        setIsRoutingVisibileToFalse: () => {
          console.log('fired setIsRoutingVisibileToFalse');
          setUser({
            ...user,
            isRoutingVisible: false
          });
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContext;

export { UserProvider };
```

And in the Routing Machine I am calling it like so:

```
  setUpdateUserMarker({
    type: 'updateMarkers',
    payload: e.latlng
  });
```

Comment: It would be nice if you embed all this code in a demo so we could reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your `case 'updateMarkers'` you are mapping the `state.markers` array but you are spreading it as top-level properties of the state.  This is actually going to create properties `0`, `1`, etc. on your state and won't update the `markers` property at all.

Run this very simplified version to see what it does.

```js
const state = {markers: [1,2,3]};
console.log({...state, ...state.markers});
```

What you *want* to do is to replace the `markers` property with the mapped array.

```
case 'updateMarkers': {
  return {
    ...state,
    markers: state.markers.map(element => {
      return element.alt === payload.alt ? { ...element, ...payload } : element;
    })
  };
}
```